# run noninteractive ssh command in background immeidately suspends the job

Tags: ssh, background-process

(1) I can run the following command and get the output successfully

```
ssh server hostname
```

(2) If I run it in background (not to background `hotname`, but to background `ssh`)

```
ssh server hostname &
```

and do nothing other than wait, I can get the output

(3) However, if before it finishes I type any key to the terminal, the job immediately turns into suspended state

```
[ZSH] suspended (tty input)    ssh server hostname
[BASH] Stopped                 ssh server hostname
```

**What is the reason for this and how to solve it?**

I just use `hostname` as an example. You can try using `sleep 5` instead if the program returns too quickly. The actual program I want to run lasts for minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ssh -T -f server hostname` as the manual page states:

```
-f requests ssh to go to background just before command execution.
This is useful if ssh is going to ask for passwords or
passphrases, but the user wants it in the background.  This
implies -n.  The recommended way to start X11 programs at a
remote site is with something like ssh -f host xterm.
If the ExitOnForwardFailure configuration option is set to “yes”,
then a client started with -f will wait for all remote port for-
wards to be successfully established before placing itself in the
background.

-T Disable pseudo-tty allocation.
```

Comment: Corrected my answer

Comment: let me try it tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: shouldn't `-T` be already implied when I specify a command to run? Also in my understanding, `-f` should be the same as putting `&` at the end except when password is required. Here I already setup `ssh` keys so password is not needed to login the server.